# CCS_ERROR The request is originated from unregistered host

Tags: javascript, nginx, web-hosting

I'm hosting a website for my school project and some of my pages are giving a weird console error and not displaying the items properly.

The error I am getting:

> [CCS_ERROR] The request is originated from unregistered host:
> 'https://tnoah.ca'.Please go to Portal / Site Integration settings to
> add it into your sites list. ccs_cc_contentloader.logError @ h.js:11
> (anonymous) @
> faa3fafd5b?mf=ASUS&pn=RTAC5300&upcean=&lang=en&market=US&host=tnoah.ca&nld=1:1

Webpage: https://tnoah.ca/shop/product.php?product=2

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue.

Setup:
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Linode
Nginx for hosting the site

Comment: I think it's quite obvious. isn't it? go to their (the third party service you're using) admin panel and add `tnoah.ca` to the list of known hosts

Comment: @s.wadhwa I am using a linode so I have no control panel it is a Ubuntu server, it would have to be something I'd have to change in the terminal.